# Sketch: Cog with rounded corners

Tags: sketch-app, anchor-point, corners

I am new to Sketch and have been using Illustrator before.

Now I made a cog in sketch, however I don't want it to have hard edges, but rather rounded ones. Here is how I made my cog in Sketch:

[image]

Now when I select the shape, I can round corners, however it will only round the corners of the rectangles:

[image: rounded corners outcome in sketch]

When I flatten the shape rounding corners for the "inner edges" (don't know what to call them) is greyed out:

[image]

In Illustrator however this is only a matter of a few clicks:

[image: Illustrator Procedure]

Here a better look at the desired outcome:

[image]

There surely is a way to do that in sketch, I figure. I'd be very thankful if someone could teach me how :)

Comment: As far as I am aware, in Sketch it is not possible to round corners on path segments that aren’t straight lines. In your example, the segments you’re trying to round are bézier curves. (Yep, Illustrator can do it.)

Comment: If you have access to Illustrator, it’s probably best to just create the icon in it, and then copy it back into Sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Sketch user, however if it's not possible to round the corners automatically, then it would be possible to do it manually.

- Create one tooth of a cog wheel, by drawing a rounded rectangle over a circle, uniting, and manually editing the curve by adding an extra anchor/node
- One half of the circle should suffice, as you can delete the other
  half, reflect the part with the rounded tooth, and do a boolean
  operation to unite it
- Then duplicate and rotate the tooth around a circle
- Then do a boolean operation to unite all the pieces

Here's a quick animated proof of concept (done in Inkscape), but I'm pretty sure it could be done in any vector image editor, with basic operations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have come in Sketch is by adding extra vector point (correct name?) on the bézier curves and then converting the the corners to the "straight" type.

[image: Cogwheel shape.]

[image: Adding extra vector points on the bézier curves.]

[image: Converting to straight path segments and rounding the corners.]

This is somewhat of a hack and I look forward to hear if there is some better approach!