# Distorted SVG icon when exporting from Sketch

Tags: svg, export, sketch-app, icon

I am getting a strange result when exporting an SVG icon from Sketch.

I am trying to export this mail icon that is made up of two masked triangles and an outer rectangle (all using an outside border):

[image]

The resulting SVG is misaligned, with some of the icon missing:

[image]

I am fairly new to Sketch and graphic design in general.

I suspect this has something to do with my groups, masks, or incorrectly 'flattening' the icon.

Any help is much appreciated.

[Generated SVG Code](https://gist.github.com/adamjoyce/55bcb648548858aae9c767b5dabe5a01)

Edit 1 - Result when I Union all the layers:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you export it:

1) Select all the layers and then select `Layer > Combine > Union` (you may have already done this step)

2) Then, with your newly united shape (that still has multiple layers within it, `Layer > Combine > Flatten`. Your shape should now be a single layer / single vector path and you should have no problems when you export.

Comment: When I Union all the layers it distorts the letter shape (I think because of the way I have used two triangles with borders and masks) - I've put the result in an edit of the main question.  Is this a case where I have to try and construct the letter shape differently?

Comment: I don't know how masks interact with Union; I'd suggest constructing this without masks. If you don't know how, check out this answer for some hints about deleting vector points (instead of masking): https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119722/how-do-i-create-a-rectangle-with-rounded-circle-incision-in-sketch/119862#119862. 

If you still need help, let me know.

Comment: For anyone struggling with a similar issue I can confirm that Unioning two shapes, each with a mask, does not produce the desired result.  As Brian suggested I created the letter without the masks.  I converted the triangles to outlines and then intersected them with the rectangles I was previously using as the masks.  From here you can Union and flatten as described in Brian's answer.